# JS SweetAlert2 not working in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, safari, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have implemented sweetalert2, in chrome, firefox, and in microsoft edge they work great! However in safari the alert never even shows and also jams up the site and makes it unusable. Is there any known issues with this or workarounds that I should be doing?

Its essential to the functionality of the site since they contain buttons and actions. So I cant just bypass it if the browser is safari.

EDIT: Turns out I am getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise in sweetalert.js on line 827.

Any ideas? Thank you!

My current code implementation:
welcome.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.css"/>
.
..
...    
function loadalert(){
        swal({
            title: 'Welcome to my website!',
            html: 'test message!',
            type: 'info',
            showCancelButton: false,
            confirmButtonText: 'Proceed'
        }).then(function () {

        });
    }
.
..
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert2.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve] - we need to see what you did - click the `<>` and create something we can test

Comment: thank you, I will revise my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some digging and testing I found the answer. If sweetalert2 does not work for safari they have a include you can call for more browser support which is:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
```

Please read for more information

> https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2#usage

Comment: I have the same problem but in NextJS...so I tried to import Core JS like: `import 'core-js/actual';` but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly it was happening to me **because I was using minified versions**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.10/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.10/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
```

**After I removed '.min' part**, it started to work on mobile phones

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.10/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.10/dist/sweetalert2.css">
```